# Should we await this line of code as we are not hitting the database here?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, entity-framework-core

My requirement is to check if the contactType object is added in the dbcontext object before checking in the DB.I have done that by using the ChangeTracker Method. I have a question regarding the use of await on that.
Q1. Since we are not hitting the DB, do we need to await that as that entry is added to the object in memory(i.e dbcontext) and we are doing a check on that.

```
 

    public async Task<ContactType> GetOrCreateContactType(string contactTypeName)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contactTypeName))
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                    ContactType contactType;
                    contactType = _dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                                                       .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added && x.Entity is ContactType)
                                                       .Select(x => x.Entity as ContactType)
                                                       .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name.ToUpper() == contactTypeName.ToUpper());
                    if (contactType != null)
                    {
                        return contactType;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        contactType = await _dbContext.ContactTypes.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Name.ToUpper() == contactTypeName.ToUpper());
                        if (contactType != null)
                        {
                            return contactType;
                        }
                    }
                    //create if ContactType does not exists:
                    contactType = new ContactType()
                    {
                        Name = contactTypeName
                    };
                    _dbContext.ContactTypes.Add(contactType);
                    return contactType;
                }
```

OR THIS

```
public async Task<ContactType> GetOrCreateContactType(string contactTypeName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contactTypeName))
            {
                return null;
            }
            ContactType contactType=null;
             await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                contactType = _dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                                                 .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added && x.Entity is ContactType)
                                                 .Select(x => x.Entity as ContactType)
                                                 .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name.ToUpper() == contactTypeName.ToUpper());
            });
            if (contactType != null)
            {
                return contactType;
            }
            else
            {
                contactType = await _dbContext.ContactTypes.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Name.ToUpper() == contactTypeName.ToUpper());
                if (contactType != null)
                {
                    return contactType;
                }
            }
            //create if ContactType does not exists:
            contactType = new ContactType()
            {
                Name = contactTypeName
            };
            _dbContext.ContactTypes.Add(contactType);
            return contactType;
        }
```

Comment: So the only difference is the `Task.Run` and the `await` before it?

Comment: Yes. That is the difference.

Comment: Why would you want to run that code on the ThreadPool?

Comment: Use the first code sample.